# Android OpenGL 2.0 FloatBuffers performances and VBOs

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, buffer

I'm making game in Android OpenGL 2.0. And I need to refresh UVs and Vertices buffers every frame. I draw on Surface with this code:

```
         GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
         GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,mTexture);

         GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
         GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mTexCoordLoc );

         GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3,
                                         GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                         0, vertexBuffer);
         GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                        false,
                        0, uvBuffer);

          GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, matrix, 0);
          GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLoc, 0);

          GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, mIndices.length,
                   GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

          GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
          GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);
```

Refresh buffers with:

```
private void updateVerticesBuffer()
        {
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mVertices.length * 4);
            bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
            vertexBuffer.put(mVertices);
            vertexBuffer.position(0);
        }

        private void updateUvsBuffer()
        {
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mUvs.length * 4);
            bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            uvBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
            uvBuffer.put(mUvs);
            uvBuffer.position(0);
        }
```

And use this shaders:

```
/* SHADER Solid
 * 
 * This shader is for rendering a colored primitive.
 * 
 */
public static final String vs_SolidColor =
    "uniform    mat4        uMVPMatrix;" +
    "attribute  vec4        vPosition;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
    "}";

public static final String fs_SolidColor =
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5,0,0,1);" +
    "}"; 

/* SHADER Image
 * 
 * This shader is for rendering 2D images straight from a texture
 * No additional effects.
 * 
 */
public static final String vs_Image =
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
    "attribute vec2 a_texCoord;" +
    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
    "  v_texCoord = a_texCoord;" +
    "}";

public static final String fs_Image =
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
    "uniform sampler2D s_texture;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord );" +
    "}";
```

Is possible to refresh buffers faster? Is VBOs faster than this? 
How can I use VBOs in this code? I searched internet but I didn't find any good tutorial. I need to transform this code to use VBOs.

Comment: The VBOs will most likely not be faster if you update the vertices every single frame but you can try it anyway. What issue are you facing creating the VBO? Its not a rocket science, all you need to do is create the buffer, send the data to it. Then just bind the buffer before drawing and remember to set NULL as the attribute pointer. Rest of the code should be more or less the same. So instead of saving the vertexBuffer you only need to save the buffer ID you receive when generating it.

Comment: I'm novice and i need some example codes to understand. Do you know how to make high performance for buffers, i saw AndEngine have buffer 5x faster than normal, but i don't know how to implement this buffer.